# Compute objects moving with arrows and mouse

Tags: c++, opengl, math

I am doing a maya simulator application with openGL, everything is progressing pretty well. Just have only one trouble, i can not calculate 100% accuracy of moving object by mouse.
I'm using the scaling of arrows in 3D coordinates and arrows in the screen coordinates and multiplying it with some scaling to calculate the degree of motion in the x and y direction of the screen coordinates. .
But these calculations do not give high accuracy, the mouse is deviated from the arrow. I need it always on the moving arrows, meaning that the accuracy is almost 100%
Anyone who has ideas or comments on this issue will always be appreciated

[image]

This is some code i try:

```
gluProject((GLdouble)x3DVertex, (GLdouble)y3DVertex, (GLdouble)z3DVertex, modelMatrix, projectMatrix, viewport, &xScreenVertex, &yScreenVertex, &zScreenVertex);

if (axis == 0)
{
gluProject((GLdouble)x3DVertex + 1, (GLdouble)y3DVertex, (GLdouble)z3DVertex, modelMatrix, projectMatrix, viewport, &xScreenArrow, &yScreenArrow, &zScreenArrow);
}
else if (axis == 1)
{
gluProject((GLdouble)x3DVertex, (GLdouble)y3DVertex + 1, (GLdouble)z3DVertex, modelMatrix, projectMatrix, viewport, &xScreenArrow, &yScreenArrow, &zScreenArrow);
}
else
{
gluProject((GLdouble)x3DVertex, (GLdouble)y3DVertex, (GLdouble)z3DVertex + 1, modelMatrix, projectMatrix, viewport, &xScreenArrow, &yScreenArrow, &zScreenArrow);
}
float totalScaleXY = abs(xScreenArrow - xScreenVertex) + abs(yScreenArrow - yScreenVertex);
scaleX = abs(xScreenArrow - xScreenVertex) / totalScaleXY;
scaleY = abs(yScreenArrow - yScreenVertex) / totalScaleXY;
float lengthArrowOnScreen = sqrt(pow((xScreenArrow - xScreenVertex), 2) + pow((yScreenArrow - yScreenVertex), 2));
scale3dAndScreen = 1 / lengthArrowOnScreen;
```

This is the code I'm testing, it's not very accurate

Comment: Show the actual calculations themselves in either code or equation form

Comment: I just came to looking for ideas
My code not good for show

Comment: @David then we can not help as we can not see what is wrong with code/equations you do not show us. Also the description is vague  mouse is deviated how? have correct direction and is running away or oscillating?  or the direction is not correct? or what?

Comment: I just ask some code,take a look,please

Comment: Do you have any ideal to fix it right?

Comment: @David to notify user `nick` you need to add `@nick` to your comment and site will do the rest. I do not use `gluProject` so not sure what exactly it does (assuming it projects screen position into 3D or the other way around). By arrows you mean arrows keys or the rendered arrows dragged by the mouse ? adding some comments in the code is a good idea as we have no idea what variable is what. I would expect mouse event handling selection and dragging. So computing screen position of the arrow comparing to mouse position and if nearby select it...

Comment: then during drag projecting mouse 2D position into 3D axis of the selected arrow. What I see instead are some scales which makes no sense (scales are changing with mouse move hence the inaccuracy)

Comment: @David added answer with example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here small ugly but very simple **C++** example of what I had in mind for this:

```cpp
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
#include <vcl.h>
#include <math.h>
#pragma hdrstop
#include "Unit1.h"
#include "gl_simple.h"
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
#pragma package(smart_init)
#pragma resource "*.dfm"
TForm1 *Form1;
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
double mview[16],mmodel[16],mproj[16];  // OpenGL matrices
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
// vector/matrix math
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
double vector_len(double *a) { return sqrt((a[0]*a[0])+(a[1]*a[1])+(a[2]*a[2])); }          // = |vector[3]|
void   vector_sub(double *c,double *a,double *b) { for (int i=0;i<3;i++) c[i]=a[i]-b[i]; }  // c[3] = a[3] - b[3]
void   matrix_mul(double *c,double *a,double *b)                                            // c[4x4] = a[4x4] * b [4x4]
    {
    double q[16];
    q[ 0]=(a[ 0]*b[ 0])+(a[ 1]*b[ 4])+(a[ 2]*b[ 8])+(a[ 3]*b[12]);
    q[ 1]=(a[ 0]*b[ 1])+(a[ 1]*b[ 5])+(a[ 2]*b[ 9])+(a[ 3]*b[13]);
    q[ 2]=(a[ 0]*b[ 2])+(a[ 1]*b[ 6])+(a[ 2]*b[10])+(a[ 3]*b[14]);
    q[ 3]=(a[ 0]*b[ 3])+(a[ 1]*b[ 7])+(a[ 2]*b[11])+(a[ 3]*b[15]);
    q[ 4]=(a[ 4]*b[ 0])+(a[ 5]*b[ 4])+(a[ 6]*b[ 8])+(a[ 7]*b[12]);
    q[ 5]=(a[ 4]*b[ 1])+(a[ 5]*b[ 5])+(a[ 6]*b[ 9])+(a[ 7]*b[13]);
    q[ 6]=(a[ 4]*b[ 2])+(a[ 5]*b[ 6])+(a[ 6]*b[10])+(a[ 7]*b[14]);
    q[ 7]=(a[ 4]*b[ 3])+(a[ 5]*b[ 7])+(a[ 6]*b[11])+(a[ 7]*b[15]);
    q[ 8]=(a[ 8]*b[ 0])+(a[ 9]*b[ 4])+(a[10]*b[ 8])+(a[11]*b[12]);
    q[ 9]=(a[ 8]*b[ 1])+(a[ 9]*b[ 5])+(a[10]*b[ 9])+(a[11]*b[13]);
    q[10]=(a[ 8]*b[ 2])+(a[ 9]*b[ 6])+(a[10]*b[10])+(a[11]*b[14]);
    q[11]=(a[ 8]*b[ 3])+(a[ 9]*b[ 7])+(a[10]*b[11])+(a[11]*b[15]);
    q[12]=(a[12]*b[ 0])+(a[13]*b[ 4])+(a[14]*b[ 8])+(a[15]*b[12]);
    q[13]=(a[12]*b[ 1])+(a[13]*b[ 5])+(a[14]*b[ 9])+(a[15]*b[13]);
    q[14]=(a[12]*b[ 2])+(a[13]*b[ 6])+(a[14]*b[10])+(a[15]*b[14]);
    q[15]=(a[12]*b[ 3])+(a[13]*b[ 7])+(a[14]*b[11])+(a[15]*b[15]);
    for(int i=0;i<16;i++) c[i]=q[i];
    }
void   matrix_mul_vector(double *c,double *a,double *b)                                     // c[3] = a[4x4] * (b[3],1)
    {
    double q[3];
    q[0]=(a[ 0]*b[0])+(a[ 4]*b[1])+(a[ 8]*b[2])+(a[12]);
    q[1]=(a[ 1]*b[0])+(a[ 5]*b[1])+(a[ 9]*b[2])+(a[13]);
    q[2]=(a[ 2]*b[0])+(a[ 6]*b[1])+(a[10]*b[2])+(a[14]);
    for(int i=0;i<3;i++) c[i]=q[i];
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
class DragDrop3D        // arrow translation controls (you need one for each objet)
    {
public:
    double *mm;         // model matrix
    double *mv;         // view matrix
    double *mp;         // projection matrix

    double o[3];        // start point
    double l[3];        // length of the arrows
    double a,b;         // size of the arrow head a length, b width/2
    int sel;            // selected axis

    DragDrop3D()
        {
        mm=NULL; mv=NULL; mp=NULL;
        o[0]=-1.0; l[0]=3.5; a=0.5;
        o[1]=-1.0; l[1]=3.5; b=0.25;
        o[2]=-1.0; l[2]=3.5; sel=-1;
        }
    DragDrop3D(DragDrop3D& a)   { *this=a; }
    ~DragDrop3D()   {}
    DragDrop3D* operator = (const DragDrop3D *a) { *this=*a; return this; }
    //DragDrop3D* operator = (const DragDrop3D &a) { ...copy... return this; }

    void project(double *scr,double *mmvp,double *obj)  // obj -> scr
        {
        matrix_mul_vector(scr,mmvp,obj);
        if (fabs(scr[2])>1e-10) scr[2]=1.0/scr[2]; else scr[2]=0.0;
        scr[0]*=scr[2];
        scr[1]*=scr[2];
        }
    void draw() // render arrows
        {
        int e;
        double ang,dang=2.0*M_PI/36.0,u0,u1,v0,v1,q=1.0/sqrt((a*a)+(b*b));
        // axis lines
        glBegin(GL_LINES);
        glColor3f(1.0,0.0,0.0); glVertex3dv(o); glVertex3d(o[0]+l[0],o[1],o[2]);
        glColor3f(0.0,1.0,0.0); glVertex3dv(o); glVertex3d(o[0],o[1]+l[1],o[2]);
        glColor3f(0.0,0.0,1.0); glVertex3dv(o); glVertex3d(o[0],o[1],o[2]+l[2]);
        glEnd();
        // cones
        glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);
        u1=b*cos(-dang);
        v1=b*sin(-dang);
        for (e=1,ang=0.0;e;ang+=dang)
            {
            if (ang>=2.0*M_PI) { ang=2.0*M_PI; e=0; }
            u0=u1; u1=b*cos(ang);
            v0=v1; v1=b*sin(ang);
            // X
            if (sel==0) glColor3f(1.0,0.0,0.0); else glColor3f(0.5,0.1,0.1);
            glNormal3f(a*q,(u0+u1)*0.5*q,(v0+v1)*0.5*q);
            glVertex3d(o[0]+l[0]  ,o[1]   ,o[2]   );
            glVertex3d(o[0]+l[0]-a,o[1]+u0,o[2]+v0);
            glVertex3d(o[0]+l[0]-a,o[1]+u1,o[2]+v1);
            glNormal3f(-1.0,0.0,0.0);
            glVertex3d(o[0]+l[0]-a,o[1],o[2]);
            glVertex3d(o[0]+l[0]-a,o[1]+u1,o[2]+v1);
            glVertex3d(o[0]+l[0]-a,o[1]+u0,o[2]+v0);
            // Y
            if (sel==1) glColor3f(0.0,1.0,0.0); else glColor3f(0.1,0.5,0.1);
            glNormal3f((u0+u1)*0.5*q,a*q,(v0+v1)*0.5*q);
            glVertex3d(o[0]   ,o[1]+l[1]  ,o[2]   );
            glVertex3d(o[0]+u1,o[1]+l[1]-a,o[2]+v1);
            glVertex3d(o[0]+u0,o[1]+l[1]-a,o[2]+v0);
            glNormal3f(0.0,-1.0,0.0);
            glVertex3d(o[0]   ,o[1]+l[1]-a,o[2]   );
            glVertex3d(o[0]+u0,o[1]+l[1]-a,o[2]+v0);
            glVertex3d(o[0]+u1,o[1]+l[1]-a,o[2]+v1);
            // Z
            if (sel==2) glColor3f(0.0,0.0,1.0); else glColor3f(0.1,0.1,0.5);
            glNormal3f((v0+v1)*0.5*q,(u0+u1)*0.5*q,a*q);
            glVertex3d(o[0]   ,o[1]   ,o[2]+l[2]  );
            glVertex3d(o[0]+v1,o[1]+u1,o[2]+l[2]-a);
            glVertex3d(o[0]+v0,o[1]+u0,o[2]+l[2]-a);
            glNormal3f(0.0,0.0,-1.0);
            glVertex3d(o[0]   ,o[1]   ,o[2]+l[2]-a);
            glVertex3d(o[0]+v0,o[1]+u0,o[2]+l[2]-a);
            glVertex3d(o[0]+v1,o[1]+u1,o[2]+l[2]-a);
            }
        glEnd();
        }
    bool mouse(double mx,double my,TShiftState sh)  // handle mouse events return if redraw is needed
        {
        if ((mm==NULL)||(mv==NULL)||(mp==NULL)) return false;
        int ql; double p[3],mmvp[16]; bool _redraw=false;
        // MVP = M*V*P
        matrix_mul(mmvp,mm,mv);
        matrix_mul(mmvp,mmvp,mp);
        // convert screen coords to <-1,+1> GL NDC
        mx=    (2.0*mx/double(xs))-1.0;
        my=1.0-(2.0*my/double(ys))    ;
        // mouse left button state (last,actual)
        ql=sh.Contains(ssLeft);
        // select (no mouse button)
        if (!ql)
            {
            int sel0=sel; sel=-1;
            // arrowhead center                         screen x,y    distance to mouse               select if close
            p[0]=o[0]+l[0]-0.5*a; p[1]=o[1]; p[2]=o[2]; project(p,mmvp,p); p[0]-=mx; p[1]-=my; p[2]=0.0; if (vector_len(p)<=0.5*b) sel=0;   // X
            p[1]=o[1]+l[1]-0.5*a; p[0]=o[0]; p[2]=o[2]; project(p,mmvp,p); p[0]-=mx; p[1]-=my; p[2]=0.0; if (vector_len(p)<=0.5*b) sel=1;   // Y
            p[2]=o[2]+l[2]-0.5*a; p[1]=o[1]; p[0]=o[0]; project(p,mmvp,p); p[0]-=mx; p[1]-=my; p[2]=0.0; if (vector_len(p)<=0.5*b) sel=2;   // Z
            _redraw=(sel0!=sel);
            }
        // drag arrowhead center into mouse position (active button)
        if ((ql)&&(sel>=0)&&(sel<3))
            {
            int i;
            double len0,len;
            double p0[3],dp[3]={0.0,0.0,0.0},t,dt,q[3]={mx,my,0.0};
            // selected arrowhead position,direction
            for (i=0;i<3;i++) p0[i]=o[i];
            p0[sel]+=l[sel]-0.5*a;
            dp[sel]=1.0;
            // "closest" intersection between axis/mouse_ray
            for (len0=-1.0,t=0.0,dt=1.0;fabs(dt)>1e-5;t+=dt)
                {
                // position on axis p(t) = p0 + t*dp
                for (i=0;i<3;i++) p[i]=p0[i]+(t*dp[i]);
                // len = distance to mouse
                project(p,mmvp,p);
                vector_sub(p,p,q); p[2]=0.0;
                len=vector_len(p);
                // handle iteration step
                if (len0<-0.5) len0=len;
                if (len>len0) dt=-0.1*dt;
                len0=len;
                }
            // translate by t
            double m[16]=
                {
                1.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,
                0.0,1.0,0.0,0.0,
                0.0,0.0,1.0,0.0,
                0.0,0.0,0.0,1.0,
                };
            m[12+sel]=t;
            matrix_mul(mm,m,mm);
            _redraw=true;
            }
        return _redraw;
        }
    };
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
DragDrop3D ctrl;    // I got single cube so single arrow drag drop control suffice
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void gl_draw()      // main rendering code
    {
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    glEnable(GL_CULL_FACE);
    glEnable(GL_LIGHTING);
    glEnable(GL_LIGHT0);
    glEnable(GL_COLOR_MATERIAL);

    // init
    static bool _init=true;
    if (_init)
        {
        _init=false;
        // M,V init matrices
        glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
        glPushMatrix();
        glLoadIdentity();
        glTranslated(0.0,0.0,-25.0);
        glGetDoublev(GL_MODELVIEW_MATRIX,mview);
        glLoadIdentity();
        glTranslated(-2.0,-1.0,-1.0);
        glRotated(-35.0,0.0,1.0,0.0);
        glGetDoublev(GL_MODELVIEW_MATRIX,mmodel);
        glPopMatrix();
        // matrices -> ctrl
        glGetDoublev(GL_PROJECTION_MATRIX,mproj);
        ctrl.mp=mproj;
        ctrl.mv=mview;
        ctrl.mm=mmodel;
        }
    // matrices -> OpenGL
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadMatrixd(mview);
    glMultMatrixd(mmodel);

    // draw VAO cube
    ctrl.draw();
    vao_draw(); // here render your object instead

    glFlush();
    SwapBuffers(hdc);
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
__fastcall TForm1::TForm1(TComponent* Owner):TForm(Owner)
    {
    // application init
    gl_init(Handle);
    vao_init();
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void __fastcall TForm1::FormDestroy(TObject *Sender)
    {
    // application exit
    gl_exit();
    vao_exit();
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void __fastcall TForm1::FormResize(TObject *Sender)
    {
    // window resize
    gl_resize(ClientWidth,ClientHeight);
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void __fastcall TForm1::FormPaint(TObject *Sender)
    {
    // window repaint
    gl_draw();
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void __fastcall TForm1::FormMouseWheel(TObject *Sender, TShiftState Shift, int WheelDelta, TPoint &MousePos, bool &Handled)
    {
    // mouse wheel translates camera (like zoom)
    GLfloat dz=2.0;
    if (WheelDelta<0) dz=-dz;
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glPushMatrix();
    glLoadMatrixd(mview);
    glTranslatef(0,0,dz);
    glGetDoublev(GL_MODELVIEW_MATRIX,mview);
    glPopMatrix();
    gl_draw();
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
// mouse events
void __fastcall TForm1::FormMouseDown(TObject *Sender, TMouseButton Button,TShiftState Shift, int X, int Y) { if (ctrl.mouse(X,Y,Shift)) gl_draw(); }
void __fastcall TForm1::FormMouseUp(TObject *Sender, TMouseButton Button,TShiftState Shift, int X, int Y) { if (ctrl.mouse(X,Y,Shift)) gl_draw(); }
void __fastcall TForm1::FormMouseMove(TObject *Sender, TShiftState Shift, int X, int Y) { if (ctrl.mouse(X,Y,Shift)) gl_draw(); }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

It is based on this: [simple complete GL+VAO/VBO+GLSL+shaders example in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31913542/2521214) where you will find more info and the `gl_simple.h` I am using for this. The code is **VCL** based so ignore the **VCL** stuff and port the events to your kind of programming.

The program is using just **OpenGL 1.0 API** (appart of the VAO/VBO cube representing my object) so it does not need anything apart `math.h` for `sin,cos,fabs` functions.

The idea is to have one control `DragDrop3D` object per each controlable object in the world/scene. Init each first and then call `mouse` for each on every mouse event and redraw if needed.

Here small preview:

[image: preview]

Sadly my **GIF** capture **SW** does not catch mouse cursor but it matches the movement exactly.

I was too lazy to compute the intersection between axises directly instead I iterate to find closest match (that `for` loop with `dt`). That part could be replaced by intersection equation.

The axises are bounded to the x,y,z axises of the object coordinate system (`mm,mmodel`).

For more objects you should also add locks so only one object can be selected ...

**PS.** see related:
- [OpenGL ray OBB intersection](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52905600/2521214)

Comment: I have found my own way for a long time. But one more lesson will be much better

Comment: Thank for this ^^