# glReadPixels and gluUnProject do not work properly

Tags: c++, qt, opengl

I am trying to get the real coordinates by using `glReadPixels` and `gluUnProject`, but it does not work.

```
void GLWidget::resizeGL(int Width, int Height)
{
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glOrtho(-100.0, 100.0, -100.0, 100.0, -100.0, 100.0);
    glViewport(0, 0, (GLint)Width, (GLint)Height);

    currentWidth = Width;
    currentHeight = Height;
}

...

void GLWidget::plotAxis()
{
    GLdouble xc,yc,zc;

    glPointSize(7.0);
    // Test points
        glColor3f(0, 0, 0);
        glBegin(GL_POINTS);
        glVertex3f(30, 10, 0);
        glVertex3f(40, 10, 10);
        glVertex3f(50, 10, -10);
        glEnd();

}
...
void GLWidget::pickGeometry()
{

    makeCurrent();
    GLint viewport[4];
    GLdouble modelview[16];
    GLdouble projection[16];
    GLfloat winX = 0.0, winY = 0.0, winZ = 0.0;
    GLdouble posX = 0.0, posY = 0.0, posZ = 0.0;

    glGetDoublev(GL_MODELVIEW_MATRIX, modelview);
    glGetDoublev(GL_PROJECTION_MATRIX, projection);
    glGetIntegerv(GL_VIEWPORT, viewport);

    this->cursorX=QCursor::pos().x();
    this->cursorY=QCursor::pos().y();

    winX = cursorX;
    winY = viewport[3] - cursorY;

// obtain Z position
    glReadPixels(winX, winY, 1, 1, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT, GL_FLOAT, &winZ);

// obtain global coordinates
    gluUnProject(winX, winY, winZ, modelview, projection, viewport, &posX, &posY, &posZ);

    qDebug() << "win XYZ" << winX << winY << winZ;
    qDebug() << "pos XYZ" << posX << posY << posZ;
}

void GLWidget::mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *event)
{
    pressPosition = event->pos();
    if(event->button()==Qt::LeftButton)
    {
    pickGeometry();

    }
}
```

click on point *30, 10, 0* gives

> win XYZ 1190 53 0
>   pos XYZ 137.762 -82.3627 100

click on point *40, 10, 10* gives

> win XYZ 1239 51 0
>   pos XYZ 147.552 -83.0283 100.

could you point me where I am wrong?

Comment: Not programing in your environment nor using GLU for this but guessing from your `y` coordinates your `y` axis is wrong ...  beware that window `y` axis usually starts at top of window and points down ... while OpenGL `y` axis starts at bottom and points up .... so you are most likely picking mirrored `y` position from what you think you are picking... btw I am doing the stuff like this: [OpenGL 3D-raypicking with high poly meshes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51764105/2521214) however that is for perspective projection ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The coordinates provided by `QCursor::pos()` are screen coordinates.
See [`QPoint QCursor::pos()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcursor.html#pos):

> Returns the **position** of the cursor (hot spot) of the primary screen **in global screen coordinates**.

But, the coordinates provided by `QMouseEvent::pos()` are coordinates relativ to the widget.
See [`QPoint QMouseEvent::pos() const`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmouseevent.html#pos):

> Returns the **position** of the mouse cursor, **relative to the widget that received the event**.

This means you have to use the position received by the mouse event instead of `QCursor::pos()`, to solve your issue:

```
void GLWidget::mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *event)
{
    pressPosition = event->pos();    

    .....
}

void OGLWidget::pickGeometry()
{
    makeCurrent();

    GLint viewport[4];
    GLdouble modelview[16];
    GLdouble projection[16];
    glGetDoublev(GL_MODELVIEW_MATRIX, modelview);
    glGetDoublev(GL_PROJECTION_MATRIX, projection);
    glGetIntegerv(GL_VIEWPORT, viewport);

    cursorX = pressPosition.rx(); // <-- pressPosition instead of QCursor::pos()
    cursorY = pressPosition.ry();

    GLfloat winX = 0.0, winY = 0.0, winZ = 0.0;
    winX = (GLfloat)cursorX;
    winY = (GLfloat)(viewport[3] - cursorY);

    // obtain Z position
    glReadPixels(winX, winY, 1, 1, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT, GL_FLOAT, &winZ);

    // obtain global coordinates
    GLdouble posX = 0.0, posY = 0.0, posZ = 0.0;
    gluUnProject(winX, winY, winZ, modelview, projection, viewport, &posX, &posY, &posZ);

    qDebug() << "win XYZ" << winX << winY << winZ;
    qDebug() << "pos XYZ" << posX << posY << posZ;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Now, it works well. I spent almost one week for it.