# Why use a render buffer as a colour attachment? (OpenGL ES 2.0)

Tags: graphics, gpu, buffer, rendering, opengl-es-2.0

I'm currently developing a small hobby project for Android using OpenGL ES 2.0 and I'm looking into the differences between textures and renderbuffers as render targets of a shader. From what I understand, you can't sample renderbuffer data directly in a shader, which forces you to use textures when that becomes a necessity.

But when I look into extensions supported by my phone, I saw that the extension "GL_OES_rgb8_rgba8" allows you to define a renderbuffer that uses an rgba8 format to use for the color attachment of an FBO, not to mention that "vanilla" OGL ES2 itself already supports attaching a renderbuffer to the color attachment of an FBO.

My question is, why does this feature exist? What use does it have to render color to a renderbuffer when you can't sample from it? Am I missing some key information or programming tactics that make this useful?

Comment: In old GL you could sample color attachments in CPU code by `glReadPixels` it was used for many things like fast O(1) pixel perfect mouse selection of rendered objects and much more however in these days drivers this feature is no longer reliable :(. The only thing that works this way (I know of) is Stencil but that is only 8bit which limits the use a lot. Here an example [OpenGL 3D-raypicking with high poly meshes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51764105/2521214)

Comment: Hey Spektre, thanks for commenting to my question? So from my understanding, you mean that renderbuffers were viable to use for CPU accessing?

Comment: Yes among other things ... I think they where added to GL in pre shader times where you got just fixed function pipeline.

Comment: That makes sense, thank you!