# OpenGL ray OBB intersection

Tags: c++, opengl

I want to implement object picking in 3D so I have a `Ray` from a point on the screen towards the scene using `glm::unproject` method "it returns the Y flipped so I use its negative value", the following code success always when the object is centered on the world origin but with another object that is transformed and the camera moved or rotated it may success and may not, i simulated the ray and it is already intersect the object, all coordinates are in the world space.

```
bool Engine::IntersectBox(Ray& ray,BoundingBox* boundingBox,GLfloat& distance){
V3* v=boundingBox->getVertices();
glm::vec4 vec(v->x,v->y,v->z,1);
vec=boundingBox->getMatrix()*vec;
GLfloat minX=vec.x;
GLfloat minY=vec.y;
GLfloat minZ=vec.z;
GLfloat maxX=vec.x;
GLfloat maxY=vec.y;
GLfloat maxZ=vec.z;
for(int i=0;i<8;i++){
    v++;
    vec=glm::vec4(v->x,v->y,v->z,1);
    vec=boundingBox->getMatrix()*vec;
    minX=minX<vec.x?minX:vec.x;
    minY=minY<vec.y?minY:vec.y;
    minZ=minZ<vec.z?minZ:vec.z;
    maxX=maxX>vec.x?maxX:vec.x;
    maxY=maxY>vec.y?maxY:vec.y;
    maxZ=maxZ>vec.z?maxZ:vec.z;
}
GLfloat tMin = 0.0f;
GLfloat tMax = 100000.0f;
glm::vec3 delta=glm::vec3(boundingBox->getMatrix()[3])-ray.getOrigin();
{
    glm::vec3 xAxis=boundingBox->getMatrix()[0];
    GLfloat e = glm::dot(xAxis, delta);
    GLfloat f = glm::dot(ray.getDirection(), xAxis);
    if ( fabs(f) > 0.001f ) { // Standard case
        GLfloat min = (e+minX)/f; // Intersection with the "left" plane
        GLfloat max = (e+maxX)/f; // Intersection with the "right" plane
        if(min<max){
            tMin=min;
            tMax=max;
        }
        else{
            tMin=max;
            tMax=min;
        }
        if (tMax < tMin)
            return false;
    }
    else{
        if(-e+minX > 0.0f || -e+maxX < 0.0f)
            return false;
    }
}
{
    glm::vec3 yAxis=boundingBox->getMatrix()[1];
    GLfloat e = glm::dot(yAxis, delta);
    GLfloat f = glm::dot(ray.getDirection(), yAxis);
    if ( fabs(f) > 0.001f ){
        GLfloat min = (e+minY)/f;
        GLfloat max = (e+maxY)/f;
        if(min<max){
            tMin=glm::max(tMin,min);
            tMax=glm::min(tMax,max);
        }
        else{
            tMin=glm::max(tMin,max);
            tMax=glm::min(tMax,min);
        }
        if (tMax < tMin)
            return false;
    }else{
        if(-e+minY > 0.0f || -e+maxY < 0.0f)
            return false;
    }
}
{
    glm::vec3 zAxis=boundingBox->getMatrix()[2];
    GLfloat e = glm::dot(zAxis, delta);
    GLfloat f = glm::dot(ray.getDirection(),zAxis);
    if ( fabs(f) > 0.001f ){
        GLfloat min = (e+minZ)/f;
        GLfloat max = (e+maxZ)/f;
        if(min<max){
            tMin=glm::max(tMin,min);
            tMax=glm::min(tMax,max);
        }
        else{
            tMin=glm::max(tMin,max);
            tMax=glm::min(tMax,min);
        }
        if (tMax < tMin)
            return false;
    }else{
        if(-e+minZ > 0.0f || -e+maxZ < 0.0f)
            return false;
    }
}
distance = tMin;
return true;
}
```

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: see [OpenGL 3D-raypicking with high poly meshes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51764105/2521214) for pixel perfect `O(1)` approach without the intersection math ... you just add one rendering buffer for object index ...

Comment: I want to use the Ray-OBB intersection method because i wanna know the selected object on the CPU side to make any operations like translation rotation or scaling

Comment: so if I used the GPU to select the object can I know on CPU which object I select?

Comment: Yes the link has an old OpenGL  style example so no shaders  ... it just convert mouse position to OpenGL NDC position read depth and index buffer so CPU knows global 3D position and index of object on which you mouse point ... That is all you need ...

Comment: So you are doing something like this: [Compute objects moving with arrows and mouse](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50908533/2521214) ? I got upgraded code from that answer by using the Ray picking I linked earlier for both movement and rotation around object local axises. If youre interseted I could create an answer from it ...

Comment: great that's what i need, could you please post an answer?

Answer (score 1):

I am doing this using:

- [OpenGL 3D-raypicking with high poly meshes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51764105/2521214)

The idea is to apart of rendering to screen also render index of each object into separate unseen buffer (color attachment, stencil, shadow,...) and than just pick pixel at mouse position from this buffer and depth ... which provides 3D position of the picked point and also index of object that it belongs to. This is very fast `O(1)` at almost no performance cost.

Now You do not need OBB for your objects nor any intersection checking anymore. Instead have a local coordinate system in form of [4x4 homogenuous matrix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28075743/how-do-i-compose-a-rotation-matrix-with-human-readable-angles-from-scratch/28084380?s=1|66.9528#28084380) with which you can easily convert the 3D position picked by mouse into object local coordinates making the manipulation like translation/rotation of the object really easy.

Here is my older C++ approach of mine for this:

- [Compute objects moving with arrows and mouse](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50908533/2521214)

which does not require any additional libs and stuff. How ever I do it now using all above in fusion like this:

```cpp
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
#ifndef _OpenGLctrl3D_h
#define _OpenGLctrl3D_h
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
#include "gl/OpenGL3D_double.cpp" // vector and matrix math keyboard and mouse handler
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
static reper NULL_rep;
AnsiString dbg="";
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
class OpenGLctrl3D      // arrow translation controls (you need one for each objet)
    {
public:
    reper *rep;             // points to bounded object model matrix
    double l[3],r0,r1,r2,a; // l  - size of each straight arrow
                            // r0 - tube radius
                            // r1 - arrow radius
                            // r2 - arced arrow radius
                            // a  - arrowhead size
    double a0,a1,aa;        // start,end, cone size [rad] of the arced arrow

    OpenGLctrl3D()
        {
        rep=&NULL_rep;
        l[0]=3.5; r0=0.05; a0=  0.0*deg; a=0.10;
        l[1]=3.5; r1=0.25; a1=360.0*deg;
        l[2]=3.5; r2=0.50; aa= 15.0*deg;
        }
    OpenGLctrl3D(OpenGLctrl3D& a)   { *this=a; }
    ~OpenGLctrl3D() {}
    OpenGLctrl3D* operator = (const OpenGLctrl3D *a) { *this=*a; return this; }
    //OpenGLctrl3D* operator = (const OpenGLctrl3D &a) { ...copy... return this; }

    void draw(int sel);                 // render arrows
    void mouse_select(void* sys);       // handle [camera local] mouse events (no active button)
    void mouse_edit  (void* sys);       // handle [camera local] mouse events (active button)
    };
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
class OpenGLctrls3D     // arrow translation controls (you need one for each objet)
    {
public:
    reper *eye;                         // camera matrix
    double per[16],ndc[16];             // perspective and viewport matrices
    TShiftState sh; double mw[3],ms[3]; // actual mouse [buttons],[world units],[camera units]
    bool _redraw;                       // redraw needed?
    int sel0,sel1,_sel;                 // actualy selected item ctrl[sel0].axis=sel1 the _sel is for iteration variable
    double psel[3];                     // selected point [object local units]

    List<OpenGLctrl3D> ctrl;
    OpenGLctrls3D() { eye=&NULL_rep; matrix_one(per); matrix_one(ndc); ctrl.num=0; }
    OpenGLctrls3D(OpenGLctrls3D& a) { *this=a; }
    ~OpenGLctrls3D(){}
    OpenGLctrls3D* operator = (const OpenGLctrls3D *a) { *this=*a; return this; }
    //OpenGLctrls3D* operator = (const OpenGLctrls3D &a) { ...copy... return this; }
    void add(reper &rep,double *l,double r0,double r1,double r2,double a)   // add new control bounded to rep
        {
        // l  - size of each straight arrow
        // r0 - tube radius
        // r1 - arrow radius
        // r2 - arced arrow radius
        // a  - arrowhead size
        ctrl.add();
        OpenGLctrl3D *c=ctrl.dat+ctrl.num-1;
        c->rep=&rep;
        vector_copy(c->l,l);
        c->r0=r0;
        c->r1=r1;
        c->r2=r2;
        c->a=a;
        }
    void resize(int x0,int y0,int xs,int ys)
        {
        matrix_one(ndc);
        ndc[ 0]=+divide(2.0,double(xs));
        ndc[ 5]=-divide(2.0,double(ys));
        ndc[12]=-1.0;
        ndc[13]=+1.0;
        glGetDoublev(GL_PROJECTION_MATRIX,per);
        mouse_refresh();
        }
    void draw()
        {
        int i;
        OpenGLctrl3D *c;
        for (c=ctrl.dat,i=0;i<ctrl.num;i++,c++)
            {
            glPushMatrix();
            c->rep->use_rep();
            glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
            glMultMatrixd(c->rep->rep);
            if (i==sel0) c->draw(sel1);
             else        c->draw(-1);
            glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
            glPopMatrix();
            }
        }
    bool mouse(double mx,double my,TShiftState _sh) // handle mouse events return if redraw is needed
        {
        // mouse depth [camera units]
        ms[0]=mx; ms[1]=my; sh=_sh;
        ms[2]=glReadDepth(mx,divide(-2.0,ndc[5])-my-1,per);
        // mouse x,y [pixel] ->  <-1,+1> NDC
        matrix_mul_vector(ms,ndc,ms);
        // mouse x,y <-1,+1> NDC -> [camera units]
        scr2world(mw,ms);
        return mouse_refresh();
        }
    bool mouse_refresh()    // call after any view change
        {
        _redraw=false;
        if (!sh.Contains(ssLeft))
            {
            int _sel0=sel0; sel0=-1;
            int _sel1=sel1; sel1=-1;
            for (_sel=0;_sel<ctrl.num;_sel++) ctrl.dat[_sel].mouse_select(this);
            _redraw=((_sel0!=sel0)||(_sel1!=sel1));
            }
        else{
            if ((sel0>=0)&&(sel0<ctrl.num)) ctrl.dat[sel0].mouse_edit(this);
            }
        return _redraw;
        }
    void world2scr(double *s,double *w)
        {
        // camera [LCS]
        eye->g2l(s,w);
        // [camera units] -> <-1,+1> NDC
        s[0]=-divide(s[0]*per[0],s[2]);
        s[1]=-divide(s[1]*per[5],s[2]);
        }
    void scr2world(double *w,double *s)
        {
        // <-1,+1> NDC -> [camera units]
        w[0]=-divide(s[0]*s[2],per[0]);
        w[1]=-divide(s[1]*s[2],per[5]);
        w[2]=s[2];
        // world [GCS]
        eye->l2g(w,w);
        }
    };
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void OpenGLctrl3D::draw(int sel)
    {
    if (sel==0) glColor3f(1.0,0.0,0.0); else glColor3f(0.5,0.0,0.0); glArrowx(0.0,0.0,0.0,r0,r1,l[0],a);
    if (sel==1) glColor3f(0.0,1.0,0.0); else glColor3f(0.0,0.5,0.0); glArrowy(0.0,0.0,0.0,r0,r1,l[1],a);
    if (sel==2) glColor3f(0.0,0.0,1.0); else glColor3f(0.0,0.0,0.5); glArrowz(0.0,0.0,0.0,r0,r1,l[2],a);
    if (sel==3) glColor3f(1.0,0.0,0.0); else glColor3f(0.5,0.0,0.0); glCircleArrowyz(0.0,0.0,0.0,r2,r0,r1,a0,a1,aa);
    if (sel==4) glColor3f(0.0,1.0,0.0); else glColor3f(0.0,0.5,0.0); glCircleArrowzx(0.0,0.0,0.0,r2,r0,r1,a0,a1,aa);
    if (sel==5) glColor3f(0.0,0.0,1.0); else glColor3f(0.0,0.0,0.5); glCircleArrowxy(0.0,0.0,0.0,r2,r0,r1,a0,a1,aa);
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void OpenGLctrl3D::mouse_select(void *_sys)
    {
    OpenGLctrls3D *sys=(OpenGLctrls3D*)_sys;
    int i,x,y,z; double p[3],q[3],pm[3],t,r;
    // mouse [object local units]
    rep->g2l(pm,sys->mw);
    // straight arrows
    for (i=0;i<3;i++)
        {
        t=pm[i]; pm[i]=0.0; r=vector_len(pm); pm[i]=t;
        t=divide(l[i]-t,a);
        if ((t>=0.0)&&(t<=1.0)&&(r<=r1*t))  // straight cone
            {
            sys->sel0=sys->_sel;
            sys->sel1=i;
            vector_ld(sys->psel,0.0,0.0,0.0); sys->psel[i]=pm[i];
            }
        }
    // arced arrows
    for (i=0;i<3;i++)
        {
        if (i==0){ x=1; y=2; z=0; }
        if (i==1){ x=2; y=0; z=1; }
        if (i==2){ x=0; y=1; z=2; }
        t=atanxy(pm[x],pm[y]);
        p[x]=r2*cos(t);
        p[y]=r2*sin(t);
        p[z]=0.0;
        vector_sub(q,p,pm);
        r=vector_len(q);
        if (r<=r0*2.0)
            {
            sys->sel0=sys->_sel;
            sys->sel1=i+3;
            vector_copy(sys->psel,p);
            }
        }
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void OpenGLctrl3D::mouse_edit(void *_sys)
    {
    OpenGLctrls3D *sys=(OpenGLctrls3D*)_sys;
    // drag straight arrows (active button)
    if ((sys->sel1>=0)&&(sys->sel1<3))
        {
        double z0,z1,z2,t0;
        double q[3],q0[3],q1[3],t;
        // q0 = mouse change in 2D screen space
        rep->l2g(q0,sys->psel);                 // selected point position
        sys->world2scr(q0,q0);
        vector_sub(q0,q0,sys->ms); q0[2]=0.0;   // actual mouse position
        // q1 = selected axis step in 2D screen space
        rep->l2g(q,sys->psel);                  // selected point position
        sys->world2scr(q,q);
        vector_copy(q1,sys->psel);              // axis step
        q1[sys->sel1]+=1.0;
        rep->l2g(q1,q1);
        sys->world2scr(q1,q1);
        vector_sub(q1,q1,q); q1[2]=0.0;
        // compute approx change
        t=-vector_mul(q0,q1);                   // dot(q0,q1)
        // enhance precision of t
        int i; double len0,len,dq[3]={0.0,0.0,0.0},dt;
        // selected arrow direction
        dq[sys->sel1]=1.0;
        // closest point on axis to psel
        for (len0=-1.0,dt=0.25*t;fabs(dt)>1e-5;t+=dt)
            {
            // position on axis p(t) = p0 + t*dp
            for (i=0;i<3;i++) q[i]=sys->psel[i]+(t*dq[i]);
            // len = distance to mouse
            rep->l2g(q,q);
            sys->world2scr(q,q);
            vector_sub(q,q,sys->ms); q[2]=0.0;
            len=vector_len2(q);
            // handle iteration step
            if (len0<-0.5) len0=len;
            if (len>len0) dt=-0.1*dt;
            len0=len;
            }
        // translate by change
        double m[16]=
            {
            1.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,
            0.0,1.0,0.0,0.0,
            0.0,0.0,1.0,0.0,
            0.0,0.0,0.0,1.0,
            };
        m[12+sys->sel1]=t;
        rep->use_rep();
        matrix_mul(rep->rep,m,rep->rep);
        rep->_inv=0;
        sys->_redraw=true;
        }
    // rotate arced arrows (active button)
    if ((sys->sel1>=3)&&(sys->sel1<6))
        {
        int i,x,y,z; double t,t0,tt,dt,len,len0,q[3];
        if (sys->sel1==3){ x=1; y=2; z=0; }
        if (sys->sel1==4){ x=2; y=0; z=1; }
        if (sys->sel1==5){ x=0; y=1; z=2; }
        t0=atanxy(sys->psel[x],sys->psel[y]);
        // initial search
        for (i=10,t=0.0,dt=divide(1.0,i),len0=-1.0;i--;t+=dt)
            {
            q[x]=r2*cos(t0+t);
            q[y]=r2*sin(t0+t);
            q[z]=0.0;
            rep->l2g(q,q);
            sys->world2scr(q,q);
            vector_sub(q,q,sys->ms); q[2]=0.0;
            len=vector_len2(q);
            if ((len0<-0.5)||(len<len0)) { len0=len; tt=t; }
            }
        // closest angle to psel
        for (t=tt;fabs(dt)>0.1*deg;t+=dt)
            {
            q[x]=r2*cos(t0+t);
            q[y]=r2*sin(t0+t);
            q[z]=0.0;
            rep->l2g(q,q);
            sys->world2scr(q,q);
            vector_sub(q,q,sys->ms); q[2]=0.0;
            len=vector_len2(q);
            // handle iteration step
            if (len>len0) dt=-0.1*dt; else { tt=t; }
            len0=len;
            }
        // rotate
        if (sys->sel1==3) rep->lrotx(tt);
        if (sys->sel1==4) rep->lroty(tt);
        if (sys->sel1==5) rep->lrotz(tt);
        sys->_redraw=true;
        }
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
#endif
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Unlike the example in the link above this uses a lot of stuff not provided (from my GL engine) so you can not use it directly however it should be enough to grasp the basics. Here some external stuff it uses (not all):

I also use mine dynamic list template so:

`List<double> xxx;` is the same as `double xxx[];`

`xxx.add(5);` adds `5` to end of the list

`xxx[7]` access array element (safe)

`xxx.dat[7]` access array element (unsafe but fast direct access)

`xxx.num` is the actual used size of the array

`xxx.reset()` clears the array and set `xxx.num=0`

`xxx.allocate(100)` preallocate space for `100` items

Rendering:

```cpp
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void glArrowx(GLfloat x0,GLfloat y0,GLfloat z0,GLfloat r0,GLfloat r1,GLfloat l0,GLfloat l1)
    {
    double pos[3]={ x0, y0, z0};
    double dir[3]={1.0,0.0,0.0};
    glArrow3D(pos,dir,r0,r1,l0,l1);
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void glArrowy(GLfloat x0,GLfloat y0,GLfloat z0,GLfloat r0,GLfloat r1,GLfloat l0,GLfloat l1)
    {
    double pos[3]={ x0, y0, z0};
    double dir[3]={0.0,1.0,0.0};
    glArrow3D(pos,dir,r0,r1,l0,l1);
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void glArrowz(GLfloat x0,GLfloat y0,GLfloat z0,GLfloat r0,GLfloat r1,GLfloat l0,GLfloat l1)
    {
    double pos[3]={ x0, y0, z0};
    double dir[3]={0.0,0.0,1.0};
    glArrow3D(pos,dir,r0,r1,l0,l1);
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void glCircleArrowxy(GLfloat x0,GLfloat y0,GLfloat z0,GLfloat r,GLfloat r0,GLfloat r1,GLfloat a0,GLfloat a1,GLfloat aa)
    {
    double pos[3]={ x0, y0, z0};
    double nor[3]={0.0,0.0,1.0};
    double bin[3]={1.0,0.0,0.0};
    glCircleArrow3D(pos,nor,bin,r,r0,r1,a0,a1,aa);
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void glCircleArrowyz(GLfloat x0,GLfloat y0,GLfloat z0,GLfloat r,GLfloat r0,GLfloat r1,GLfloat a0,GLfloat a1,GLfloat aa)
    {
    double pos[3]={ x0, y0, z0};
    double nor[3]={1.0,0.0,0.0};
    double bin[3]={0.0,1.0,0.0};
    glCircleArrow3D(pos,nor,bin,r,r0,r1,a0,a1,aa);
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void glCircleArrowzx(GLfloat x0,GLfloat y0,GLfloat z0,GLfloat r,GLfloat r0,GLfloat r1,GLfloat a0,GLfloat a1,GLfloat aa)
    {
    double pos[3]={ x0, y0, z0};
    double nor[3]={0.0,1.0,0.0};
    double bin[3]={0.0,0.0,1.0};
    glCircleArrow3D(pos,nor,bin,r,r0,r1,a0,a1,aa);
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void glArrow3D(double *pos,double *dir,double r0,double r1,double l0,double l1)
    {
    int i,n=_glCircleN;
    double nn=1.0,a,da=divide(pi2,n),p[3],dp[3],x[3],y[3],p0[3],p1[3],c,s,q;
    if (l0<0.0) { da=-da; nn=-nn; l1=-l1; }
    // TBN
         if (fabs(dir[0]-dir[1])>1e-6) vector_ld(x,dir[1],dir[0],dir[2]);
    else if (fabs(dir[0]-dir[2])>1e-6) vector_ld(x,dir[2],dir[1],dir[0]);
    else if (fabs(dir[1]-dir[2])>1e-6) vector_ld(x,dir[0],dir[2],dir[1]);
    else                       vector_ld(x,1.0,0.0,0.0);
    vector_one(dir,dir);
    vector_mul(x,x,dir);
    vector_mul(y,x,dir);
    vector_mul(p0,dir,l0-l1); vector_add(p0,pos,p0);
    vector_mul(p1,dir,l0   ); vector_add(p1,pos,p1);
    // disc r0, 0
    vector_len(x,x,r0);
    vector_len(y,y,r0);
    glBegin(GL_TRIANGLE_FAN);
    vector_mul(p,dir,-nn);
    glNormal3dv(p);
    glVertex3dv(pos);
    for (a=0.0,i=0;i<=n;i++,a+=da)
        {
        vector_mul(dp,x,cos(a)); vector_add(p,pos,dp);
        vector_mul(dp,y,sin(a)); vector_add(p,p  ,dp);
        glVertex3dv(p);
        }
    glEnd();

    // tube r0, 0..l0-l1
    q=divide(1.0,r0);
    glBegin(GL_QUAD_STRIP);
    for (a=0.0,i=0;i<=n;i++,a+=da)
        {
        vector_mul( p,x,cos(a));
        vector_mul(dp,y,sin(a)); vector_add(dp,p ,dp); vector_add(p,pos,dp);
        vector_mul(dp,dp,q);
        glNormal3dv(dp);
        glVertex3dv(p);
        vector_sub(p,p,pos);
        vector_add(p,p,p0);
        glVertex3dv(p);
        }
    glEnd();

    // disc r1, l0-l1
    vector_len(x,x,r1);
    vector_len(y,y,r1);
    glBegin(GL_TRIANGLE_FAN);
    vector_mul(p,dir,-nn);
    glNormal3dv(p);
    glVertex3dv(p0);
    for (a=0.0,i=0;i<=n;i++,a+=da)
        {
        vector_mul(dp,x,cos(a)); vector_add(p,p0 ,dp);
        vector_mul(dp,y,sin(a)); vector_add(p,p  ,dp);
        glVertex3dv(p);
        }
    glEnd();

    // cone r1..0, l0-l1..l0
    glBegin(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP);
    q=divide(1.0,sqrt((l1*l1)+(r1*r1)));
    for (a=0.0,i=0;i<=n;i++,a+=da)
        {
        vector_mul( p,x,cos(a));
        vector_mul(dp,y,sin(a)); vector_add(dp,p ,dp); vector_add(p,p0,dp);
        vector_mul(dp,dp,q);
        glNormal3dv(dp);
        glVertex3dv(p);
        glVertex3dv(p1);
        }
    glEnd();
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void glCircleArrow3D(double *pos,double *nor,double *bin,double r,double r0,double r1,double a0,double a1,double aa)
    {
    int e,i,j,N=3*_glCircleN;
    double U[3],V[3],u,v;
    double a,b,da,db=pi2/double(_glCircleN-1),a2,rr;
    double *ptab,*p0,*p1,*n0,*n1,*pp,p[3],q[3],c[3],n[3],tan[3];
    // buffers
    ptab=new double [12*_glCircleN]; if (ptab==NULL) return;
    p0=ptab+(0*_glCircleN);
    n0=ptab+(3*_glCircleN);
    p1=ptab+(6*_glCircleN);
    n1=ptab+(9*_glCircleN);
    // prepare angles
    a2=a1; da=db; aa=fabs(aa);
    if (a0>a1) { da=-da; aa=-aa; }
    a1-=aa;
    // compute missing basis vectors
    vector_copy(U,nor);         // U is normal to arrow plane
    vector_mul(tan,nor,bin);    // tangent is perpendicular to normal and binormal
    // arc interpolation a=<a0,a2>
    for (e=0,j=0,a=a0;e<5;j++,a+=da)
        {
        // end conditions
        if (e==0)   // e=0
            {
            if ((da>0.0)&&(a>=a1)) { a=a1; e++; }
            if ((da<0.0)&&(a<=a1)) { a=a1; e++; }
            rr=r0;
            }
        else{       // e=1,2,3,4
            if ((da>0.0)&&(a>=a2)) { a=a2; e++; }
            if ((da<0.0)&&(a<=a2)) { a=a2; e++; }
            rr=r1*fabs(divide(a-a2,a2-a1));
            }
        // compute actual tube segment center c[3]
        u=r*cos(a);
        v=r*sin(a);
        vector_mul(p,bin,u);
        vector_mul(q,tan,v);
        vector_add(c,p,  q);
        vector_add(c,c,pos);
        // V is unit direction from arrow center to tube segment center
        vector_sub(V,c,pos);
        vector_one(V,V);
        // tube segment interpolation
        for (b=0.0,i=0;i<N;i+=3,b+=db)
            {
            u=cos(b);
            v=sin(b);
            vector_mul(p,U,u);      // normal
            vector_mul(q,V,v);
            vector_add(n1+i,p,q);
            vector_mul(p,n1+i,rr);  // vertex
            vector_add(p1+i,p,c);
            }
        if (e>1)                    // recompute normals for cone
            {
            for (i=3;i<N;i+=3)
                {
                vector_sub(p,p0+i  ,p1+i);
                vector_sub(q,p1+i-3,p1+i);
                vector_mul(p,p,q);
                vector_one(n1+i,p);
                }
            vector_sub(p,p0    ,p1);
            vector_sub(q,p1+N-3,p1);
            vector_mul(p,q,p);
            vector_one(n1,p);
            if (da>0.0) for (i=0;i<N;i+=3) vector_neg(n1+i,n1+i);
            if (e==  3) for (i=0;i<N;i+=3) vector_copy(n0+i,n1+i);
            }
        // render base disc
        if (!j)
            {
            vector_mul(n,V,U);
            glBegin(GL_TRIANGLE_FAN);
            glNormal3dv(n);
            glVertex3dv(c);
            if (da<0.0) for (i=  0;i< N;i+=3) glVertex3dv(p1+i);
            else        for (i=N-3;i>=0;i-=3) glVertex3dv(p1+i);
            glEnd();
            }
        // render tube
        else{
            glBegin(GL_QUAD_STRIP);
            if (da<0.0) for (i=0;i<N;i+=3)
                {
                glNormal3dv(n0+i); glVertex3dv(p0+i);
                glNormal3dv(n1+i); glVertex3dv(p1+i);
                }
            else for (i=0;i<N;i+=3)
                {
                glNormal3dv(n1+i); glVertex3dv(p1+i);
                glNormal3dv(n0+i); glVertex3dv(p0+i);
                }
            glEnd();
            }
        // swap buffers
        pp=p0; p0=p1; p1=pp;
        pp=n0; n0=n1; n1=pp;
        // handle r0 -> r1 edge
        if (e==1) a-=da;
        if ((e==1)||(e==2)||(e==3)) e++;
        }
    // release buffers
    delete[] ptab;
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void glLinearArrow3D(double *pos,double *dir,double r0,double r1,double l,double al)
    {
    int e,i,N=3*_glCircleN;
    double U[3],V[3],W[3],u,v;
    double a,da=pi2/double(_glCircleN-1),r,t;
    double *ptab,*p0,*p1,*n1,*pp,p[3],q[3],c[3],n[3];
    // buffers
    ptab=new double [9*_glCircleN]; if (ptab==NULL) return;
    p0=ptab+(0*_glCircleN);
    p1=ptab+(3*_glCircleN);
    n1=ptab+(6*_glCircleN);
    // compute basis vectors
    vector_one(W,dir);
    vector_ld(p,1.0,0.0,0.0);
    vector_ld(q,0.0,1.0,0.0);
    vector_ld(n,0.0,0.0,1.0);
    a=fabs(vector_mul(W,p));            pp=p; t=a;
    a=fabs(vector_mul(W,q)); if (t>a) { pp=q; t=a; }
    a=fabs(vector_mul(W,n)); if (t>a) { pp=n; t=a; }
    vector_mul(U,W,pp);
    vector_mul(V,U,W);
    vector_mul(U,V,W);
    for (e=0;e<4;e++)
        {
        // segment center
        if (e==0) { t=0.0;  r= r0; }
        if (e==1) { t=l-al; r= r0; }
        if (e==2) { t=l-al; r= r1; }
        if (e==3) { t=l;    r=0.0; }
        vector_mul(c,W,t);
        vector_add(c,c,pos);
        // tube segment interpolation
        for (a=0.0,i=0;i<N;i+=3,a+=da)
            {
            u=cos(a);
            v=sin(a);
            vector_mul(p,U,u);      // normal
            vector_mul(q,V,v);
            vector_add(n1+i,p,q);
            vector_mul(p,n1+i,r);   // vertex
            vector_add(p1+i,p,c);
            }
        if (e>2)                    // recompute normals for cone
            {
            for (i=3;i<N;i+=3)
                {
                vector_sub(p,p0+i  ,p1+i);
                vector_sub(q,p1+i-3,p1+i);
                vector_mul(p,p,q);
                vector_one(n1+i,p);
                }
            vector_sub(p,p0    ,p1);
            vector_sub(q,p1+N-3,p1);
            vector_mul(p,q,p);
            vector_one(n1,p);
            }
        // render base disc
        if (!e)
            {
            vector_neg(n,W);
            glBegin(GL_TRIANGLE_FAN);
            glNormal3dv(n);
            glVertex3dv(c);
            for (i=0;i<N;i+=3) glVertex3dv(p1+i);
            glEnd();
            }
        // render tube
        else{
            glBegin(GL_QUAD_STRIP);
            for (i=0;i<N;i+=3)
                {
                glNormal3dv(n1+i);
                glVertex3dv(p0+i);
                glVertex3dv(p1+i);
                }
            glEnd();
            }
        // swap buffers
        pp=p0; p0=p1; p1=pp;
        }
    // release buffers
    delete[] ptab;
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

vector and matrix math:

```
// cross product: W = U x V
W.x=(U.y*V.z)-(U.z*V.y)
W.y=(U.z*V.x)-(U.x*V.z)
W.z=(U.x*V.y)-(U.y*V.x)
// dot product: a = (U.V)
a=U.x*V.x+U.y*V.y+U.z*V.z
// abs of vector a = |U|
a=sqrt((U.x*U.x)+(U.y*U.y)+(U.z*U.z))
```

`vector_mul(a[3],b[3],c[3])` is cross product `a = b x c`

`a = vector_mul(b[3],c[3])` is dot product `a = (b.c)`

`vector_one(a[3],b[3])` is unit vector `a = b/|b|`

`vector_copy(a[3],b[3])` is just copy `a = b`

`vector_add(a[3],b[3],c[3])` is adding `a = b + c`

`vector_sub(a[3],b[3],c[3])` is substracting `a = b - c`

`vector_neg(a[3],b[3])` is negation `a = -b`

`vector_ld(a[3],x,y,z)` is just loading `a = (x,y,z)`

The `reper` class is just holding direct and inverse 4x4 matrix representing 3D coordinate system. Its implementation depends on your coordinate system and gfx notation (matrix row/column major order, multiplication order etc...) Everything you need to implement it is in the **4x4 homogenuous matrix** link above.

**Now finally the usage:**

Here is my BDS2006 C++/VCL/OpenGL project source code:

```cpp
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
#include <vcl.h>
#include <math.h>
#pragma hdrstop
#include "Unit1.h"
#include "OpenGLctrl3D.h" // only this is important
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
#pragma package(smart_init)
#pragma resource "*.dfm"
TForm1 *Form1; // this form/window
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
reper eye,obj; // camera and object matrices
double perspective[16]; // projection matrix
OpenGLscreen scr; // my GL engine can ignore this
OpenGLctrls3D ctrl; // control component (important)
bool _redraw=true; // need repaint ?
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void gl_draw()      // main rendering code
    {
    _redraw=false;
    scr.cls();
    glEnable(GL_CULL_FACE);
    glEnable(GL_LIGHTING);
    glEnable(GL_LIGHT0);
    glEnable(GL_COLOR_MATERIAL);

    // set view
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    eye.use_inv();
    glLoadMatrixd(eye.inv);

    // draw all controls
    ctrl.draw();

    // draw all objects
    glPushMatrix();
    obj.use_rep();
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glMultMatrixd(obj.rep);

    glColor3f(1.0,1.0,1.0);
//  glBox(0.0,0.0,0.0,1.0,1.0,1.0);

    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glPopMatrix();

    scr.exe();
    scr.rfs();
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
__fastcall TForm1::TForm1(TComponent* Owner):TForm(Owner)
    {
    // application init
    scr.init(this);
    scr.views[0].znear=0.1;
    scr.views[0].zfar=100.0;
    scr.views[0].zang=60.0;
    // matrices
    eye.reset();
    eye.gpos_set(vector_ld(0.0,0.0,+5.0));
    eye.lrotz(25.0*deg);
    obj.reset();
    obj.gpos_set(vector_ld(-1.0,-0.5,-1.0));
    obj.lroty(-35.0*deg);
    // controls
    ctrl.eye=&eye;
    ctrl.add(obj,vector_ld(2.5,2.5,2.5),0.04,0.10,1.25,0.5);
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void __fastcall TForm1::FormDestroy(TObject *Sender)
    {
    // application exit
    scr.exit();
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void __fastcall TForm1::FormResize(TObject *Sender)
    {
    // window resize
    scr.resize();
    ctrl.resize(scr.x0,scr.y0,scr.xs,scr.ys);
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void __fastcall TForm1::FormPaint(TObject *Sender)
    {
    // window repaint
    gl_draw();
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void __fastcall TForm1::FormMouseWheel(TObject *Sender, TShiftState Shift, int WheelDelta, TPoint &MousePos, bool &Handled)
    {
    // mouse wheel translates camera (like zoom)
    GLfloat dz=2.0;
    if (WheelDelta>0) dz=-dz;
    eye.lpos_set(vector_ld(0.0,0.0,dz));
    ctrl.mouse_refresh();
    _redraw=true;
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
// mouse events
void __fastcall TForm1::FormMouseDown(TObject *Sender, TMouseButton Button,TShiftState Shift, int X, int Y) { _redraw|=ctrl.mouse(X,Y,Shift); }
void __fastcall TForm1::FormMouseUp(TObject *Sender, TMouseButton Button,TShiftState Shift, int X, int Y)   { _redraw|=ctrl.mouse(X,Y,Shift); }
void __fastcall TForm1::FormMouseMove(TObject *Sender, TShiftState Shift, int X, int Y)                     { _redraw|=ctrl.mouse(X,Y,Shift); }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void __fastcall TForm1::Timer1Timer(TObject *Sender)
    {
//  double *p=ctrl.pm; Caption=AnsiString().sprintf("(%7.3lf,%7.3lf,%7.3lf)",p[0],p[1],p[2]);
    Caption=dbg;
    //  obj.lroty(3.0*deg); ctrl.mouse_refresh(); _redraw=true;
    if (_redraw) gl_draw();
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

You can ignore the VCL and my engine related stuff. For each controlled object you should have its 4x4 transform matrix (`reper`) and a control component (OpenGLctrl3D). Then just mimic the events and add relevant calls to draw and key/mouse events for each.

Here preview how it looks like:

[image: preview]

Sadly my GIF capturer does not capture the mouse cursor so you do not see where I click/drag ... But as you can see my control is rather complex and just OBB would not help much as the rings and arrows are intersecting a lot. The choppy ness is due to GIF capture encoding but when using logarithmic depth buffer you might expect chppyness also for object far from znear plane. To remedy that you can use:

- [Linear depth buffer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42515399/2521214)

In my example I do not have any objects just single control but you get the idea ... so each object of yours should have its matrix (the same that is used for its rendering) so you just add a control referencing it. In case your objects are dynamicaly added and removed you need to add their add/removal to controls too...

The most important stuff are the functions `mouse_select` and `mouse_edit` which converts the 3D global mouse position into objetc/control local one making very easy to detect stuff like inside cone, inside cylinder, angle of rotation and translation size etc ...